# Motion in 3D Space: Finding Velocity from Distance, Launch Angle

Tags: calculus, physics, projectile-motion

The question asks:

> A bullet is fired from the ground at an angle of $45°$. What initial speed must the bullet have in order to hit the top of a $130 m$ tower located $190 m$ away? (Recall that $g=9.8 \mathrm{m/s^2}$ is the acceleration due to gravity on the earth's surface. Round your answer to three decimal places.)

I tried working this as a simple physics problem, wherein the following equations needed to be solved (sketch at bottom of post):

$$\sqrt{2}vt=190m$$
$$\sqrt{2}vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2=130m$$

for $v=$ velocity in the $x$ or $y$ direction (since 45-45-90 triangles have ratio 1-1-$\sqrt{2}$); and $a=$ the negative value of gravity.

The first equation originates from the formula $v=dt\rightarrow d=\frac{v}{t}$, while the second equation originates from the formula $d=\frac{1}{2}at^2+vt$.

When I solved the set of equations, I got $t=\sqrt{\frac{60}{4.9}}=3.49927s$ and $v=\frac{190}{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{\frac{60}{4.9}}}=\boxed{38.3938\frac{m}{s}}$.

However, my answer was marked incorrect. Any suggestions or recommendations that would **(a)** help find the correct answer and/or **(b)** provide the setup to solve the question using Calculus 3 methods would be much appreciated.

Sketch:
[image: Sketch of Problem]

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}vt$ in both equations instead of $\sqrt{2}vt$

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Seems obvious now, guess I just needed a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made mistakes for the components of the initial velocity.

$\displaystyle u_{x}=v\cos 45^{\circ}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\displaystyle u_{y}=v\sin 45^{\circ}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$